# How do a read a xdebug profile in webgrind?

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

I have setup xdebug and webgrind and I have generated a profile so I can start improving the speed of my code execution. I have displayed the profile in webgrind but I haven't got a clue what any of it means. All the googling I have done doesn't really explain any of it either.

Could someone please explain the basics of reading a webgrind report:

Invocation Count

Total Self Cost

Total Inclusive Cost

What the different colours mean

What the coloured bar means

Calls

Total Call Cost

Count

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The basic output lists all the different functions, methods, and `included`/`required` files.

- **Invocation Count:** The number of times the function has been called
- **Total Self Cost:** The total time it took to execute the raw php in this function (time taken to execute your other custom functions is excluded.)
- **Total Inclusive Cost:** Total time, including any other functions called (PHP internal, or your functions)
- **What the different colours mean?**

  - **Blue** are PHP internal functions
  - **Green** are your class methods
  - **Orange** are procedural functions
  - **Grey** is time taken to `include`, or `require` .php files.
- **What the coloured bar means?** Graphical display of breakdown of time for each type as above.
- For the last ones, I assume you've clicked the arrow to open a particular function?

  - **Calls:** The functions/methods called in executing this function
  - **Total Call Cost:** The total time executing this function, when called from the parent function
  - **Count:** Number of times the parent calls the child.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is the Self and Inclusive Cost already mulitplied by the Invocation Count? Or does it then need to be multiplied as well to get a real idea of how much time is spent?

Comment: No problem - All times are already multiplied by any count value.

Comment: These colors represent the distribution of built-in PHP functions (blue), include/require functions (lavender), class methods (green) and procedural functions (orange).

Comment: And what does the @ symbol represent? E.g.   php::spl_autoload_register @ 58

Comment: I assume time is in milliseconds?

Comment: Is the total inclusive cost in percent, when "in percent" selected? If so, how do I interpret values over 100?

Comment: "@" symbol represents the line number in appropriate source file, from which the mentioned function is called.